# docker-compose exec python the input device is not a TTY in AWS EC2 UserData

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, automation, docker-compose, tty

I am using EC2 UserData to bootstrap the instance.

TRacking log of bootstrap execution `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`, I found that the script was stopped at :

```
+ docker-compose exec web python /var/www/flask/app/db_fixtures.py
the input device is not a TTY
```

It seems like this command it's running in interactive mode, but why ? and how to force noninteractive mode for this command (docker-compose exec) ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Citing from [the `docker-compose exec` docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/):

> Commands are by default allocating a TTY, so you can use a command such as docker-compose exec web sh to get an interactive prompt.

To disable this behavior, you can either the `-T` flag to disable pseudo-tty allocation:

```
docker-compose exec -T web python /var/www/flask/app/db_fixtures.py
```

Or set the [`COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_interactive_no_cli) to 1 before running `docker-compose exec`:

```
export COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1
```

Comment: Yup.. I got it. Nevertheless , you deserve +1.

Comment: `-T` works well. However setting `COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1` gave a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` error for me.